# C# having trouble with this program

Tags: c#

https://pastebin.com/Z0GWP5Lw

```cs
int count = 0;
int i;
int j;
int quantity = 0;
string item;
decimal price = 0;
decimal subtotal;
decimal subTotal = 0;
decimal Subtotal;
decimal total;
decimal tax;
string[,] items = new string[100, 4];

subtotal = subTotal;

Subtotal = price * quantity;

tax = subtotal * 0.065M;

total = subtotal + tax;
do
{

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {

        items[i,0] = ("Enter Item Name(Enter 0 to stop): ");
        item = Console.ReadLine();

        if (items[i, 0] == "0")
        break;
        else
        count++;

        items[i,1] = ("Enter Item Price: ");
        price = (decimal)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (price > 0)
        count++;
        subTotal = subTotal + price;
        if (price <= 0)
        break;

        items[i,2] = ("Enter Item Quantity: ");
        quantity = (int)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        items[i, 3] = (Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 1]) * Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 2])).ToString();

    }
}
while (i != 0);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items[i, j], "");
        Console.WriteLine("           Count:    {0}", count);
        Console.WriteLine("        Subtotal:   ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotal));
        Console.WriteLine("     Tax(0.065%):     ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", tax));
        Console.WriteLine("           Total:    ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", total));
    }
}
```

That is the program. I am struggling to figure out what to do for the while part of the while loop. I am a novice at C#. Also when ever I run the program no text appears. How should it be typed so the user knows what to type. There is probably multiple things that need fixing in this code, so if there is anything else that needs changing please let me know.

I tried to make a program where a user would enter in an item name, the price of the item, and then the amount. These would be stored in an array. They would stop by inputting 0 for the item name and the subtotal of the item, ie: if you bought a two bananas for three dollars it would say six dollars for the bananas, and then an overall subtotal of just the base price of each thing added up without tax.

Comment: Your code is unreadable and requires too many assumptions to help you fix your issue. Update your post using a code block and copy your code as it is in your project, and don't use patebin, just post your code here and help us help you.

Comment: What are your problems with this code? What do you expect it to do, what really happens?

Comment: How do you update using a code block? I tried that when trying to post and could not figure it out.

Comment: Setting `items[i, 1]` will not display that text. Setting `item` to the ReadLine value will not update `items[i, 1]`

Comment: So how do you update items[i, 1] and display the text? I could not figure it out. Sorry if it is too much to ask.

Comment: I’m trying to display the text. Enter item name along with the other text in orange. I thought you do items[i,0] = Console.ReadLine then the text, but that gives me no overload for method ReadLine takes one arguments error. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Writing a value to the console and reading from it are two separate commands. You have already used both

Comment: C# is case sensitive. You have 3 different subtotal variables - that is just confusing

Comment: Capital S subtotal is the amount an individual item cost c amount of times.  Capital T subtotal is for the over all subtotal. What the sub total is, is the price without tax.

Comment: When you do `tax = subtotal * 0.065M` you don't "set up a relationship" that will eventually give a value to "tax" once the other values are set. In fact you are calculating "tax" once, when your app executes that line, with the values at that moment

Comment: So I only use one, or do I use both commands just differently than I am using them now? Do I put the items[i,0] on the line where item console.readline() is, and make the orange text a console.write?

Comment: Don't use `i` for two things. You have as the iteration variable and for a condition in the `while()` loop. This is bound to lead to bugs.

Comment: Are you  sure the tax is `0.065%` and not `6.5%` ?

Comment: It’s a 6.5% tax, and multiplying by 0.065 is how to calculate it. It is the same thing as dividing the subtotal by 100 and multiplying by 6.5

Comment: So does i not go in the while part of the whole loop? I had just put it there to see what the rest of the code does, and was not sure if it was the correct thing to put there.

Comment: May I give you a few suggestions? First, rename your "subtotal" variables to something more descriptive. As @HansKeﬆing pointed out, its very confusing how you currently have them. You could do something like `beforeTaxSubtotal`, `overallSubtotal`, `itemCost` or anything more descriptive then what they currently are. Next, [Set a breakpoint and start the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fdebugger%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2022#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger). Debugging can be vital to figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: After doing the debugger using break points, I see that my code does not have a bug right now. It still does not do what I want, which is add up all of the prices of the total amount of each item, and the tax and then show to total. All it is doing now is displaying 0 for the tax, subtotal and total. I think what it is doing is thinking is the 0 I input to stop the loop counts towards the multiplication which it shouldn’t. Also, when I put in 0 to stop the loop I have to do it twice. I am struggling to figure out how to solve this. Sorry for the long reply.

Comment: A "bug" is not only a crash, but also an unexpected result - which is what you have. So where should it be adding up that total amount, and why doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To help you move further along in your learning process, here is a modified version of your code. Please review and compare with yours. Hopefully the difference will tell what you want to fix to get to where you wanna go.

```
int count = 0;
int i;
int j;
int quantity = 0;
string item;
decimal price = 0;
decimal subtotal;
decimal subTotal = 0;
decimal Subtotal;
decimal total;
decimal tax;
string[,] items = new string[10, 4];

subtotal = subTotal;

Subtotal = price * quantity;

tax = subtotal * 0.065M;

total = subtotal + tax;
//do
//{

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Name(Enter 0 to stop): ");
        item = Console.ReadLine();
        items[i, 0] = item;

        if (items[i, 0] == "0")
            break;
        else
            count++;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Price: ");
        price = (decimal)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        items[i, 1] = price.ToString();


        if (price > 0)
            count++;
        subTotal = subTotal + price;
        if (price <= 0)
            break;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Quantity: ");
        quantity = (int)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        items[i, 2] = quantity.ToString();


        items[i, 3] = (Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 1]) * Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 2])).ToString();
    }


//}
//while (i != 0);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items[i, j], "");
        Console.WriteLine("           Count:    {0}", count);
        Console.WriteLine("        Subtotal:   ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotal));
        Console.WriteLine("     Tax(0.065%):     ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", tax));
        Console.WriteLine("           Total:    ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", total));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this. Even though it does not calculate the subtotal and total, this is better than I had before. I am just not sure how to get the do while loop to stop when 0 is an item name.

Comment: Try this: When you break from the for loop, easiest way is to set the value of i to 0. Then you can explore further. 

if (items[i, 0] == "0")
{ 
  i = 0;
  break;
}